# Add JPanel from another class to JFrame in another class

Tags: java, swing

As the title describes, I want to Add JPanel from another class to JFrame in another class. However, the JFrame window will display, but not with JPanel. I'm sure the JPanel is not added into JFrame. Could you please tell me where goes wrong? Thank you so much!

JFrame Class:

```
public class Test extends JFrame{
    MyTank myTank = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
  }

public Test(){
    myTank = new MyTank();
    add(myTank);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

JPanel CLass:

```
public class MyTank extends JPanel{
   public void paint(Graphics graphics){
    super.paint(graphics);
    graphics.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    graphics.fill3DRect(50,50, 50, 50, true);
  }
}
```

But if I code this this way, it actually works:

```
public class myFrameExample extends JFrame{
myPanel2 mPanel = null;  
MyTank myTank = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myFrameExample myTankShape = new myFrameExample(); 
}

public myFrameExample(){  
    mPanel = new myPanel2();  
    this.add(mPanel);  
    this.setSize(500, 500); 
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    this.setVisible(true);  
}
}

class myPanel2 extends JPanel{ 
public void paint(Graphics graphics){
    super.paint(graphics);
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    graphics.drawOval(10, 10, 50, 50);
    graphics.fillOval(50, 50, 40, 40);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo error:

```
public class MyTank extends JPanel{
   public void Paint(Graphics graphics){
               ^--- must be lower case
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. That's an error. I just corrected it and tested again, however, still doesn't work. I don't think there is logic error in my code, is it?

Comment: Did you save changes and re-compile, the code works at my end

Comment: I restarted eclipse, and after that it worked perfectly. No idea why, but your answer did solve my problem. Thank you, mate!

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying a layout for the JFrame:

```
public class Test extends JFrame{
    MyTank myTank = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
  }

public Test(){
    myTank = new MyTank();
    //setting the layout to null, you can use other layout managers for this
    setLayout(null);
    add(myTank);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't matter, as the default layout is FlowLayout. You don't need to specify layout.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a constructor specified for your MyTank class. While it is true that java provides you with a default no-arg constructor, this constructor usually doesn't do anything. In your case, while you do have a `Paint` method, you still don't have any constructor.

I would suggest changing your JPanel class to look more like this:

```
public class MyTank extends JPanel {
    public MyTank {
        //insert your code here, and possibly call your `Paint` method.
    }
    public void Paint(Graphics graphics){
        super.paint(graphics);
        graphics.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        graphics.fill3DRect(50,50, 50, 50, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't understand why I need a constructor here.